# What counts as an armored target for the purposes of the 'D4TH Blossom' SMG?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

The '[D4TH Blossom](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/D4TH_Blossom)' SMG's Level 4 upgrade is described in-game as: "*Armor piercing bullets do more damage and pass through armor*".

[image]

**What counts as an armored target?** What targets will the D4TH Blossom's bullets pass through, and what targets will take more damage? Are vehicles, aircraft, structures (like the ones you destroy in missions) or brutes considered armored for the purposes of the'D4th Blossom' SMG's Level 4 upgrade?

Note: I've read the Saint Row Wiki's [D4TH Blossom](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/D4TH_Blossom) article, where it states that it "*penetrate the hulls of light vehicles to hit targets behind them (I.E. it can shoot through a door to hit a driver), and allow it to puncture riot shields.*" So besides that, are there any other targets that are affected? Or can anyone expound on what vehicles count as a "light vehicle" or not? Will vehicles take more damage from a Level 4 D4TH Blossom?

Answer (score 2):

As you've said before it can puncture through the hulls of light armored vehicles and riot shields. I'd also assume that another armoured target would have to be one the brutes that have armor on them, like the chain gun brute.

I also believe that the flame thrower brute also has armor as well but I haven't played the game in a while and can't be certain.

Other than that I think that it could also pass through helicopters or planes to hit the pilots in the pilots seat, but other than that I think that is all.

Edit: Also to your other question as to whether the gun hurts more when it is a higher level, I believe that it isn't specifically doing damage to the vehicle and more or less used to hit the soft squishy target on the other side. If I were to guess, It would do more damage the higher level it is, but then again, that's just my guess.